# GDB SIGALRM, Alarm clock termination

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gdb, alarm

I am facing a small problem that I haven't seen before. I am trying to debug a software package and running through GDB (on Ubuntu Linux).
After few seconds/minutes, I get this message:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGALRM, Alarm clock.
The program no longer exists
```

Then, I quit GDB, restart and continue debugging...This is really annoying because I have to quit it like a 1000 times. I am wondering if anyone faced this issue before?!

I am assuming 'SIGALRM' is programmed in the source files somewhere, is there a way to run GDB without being affected as mentioned?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tell gdb to [ignore](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_39.html) the signal:

```
(gdb) handle SIGALRM ignore
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. As soon as `GDB` starts or after setting the breakpoint and running, or it doesn't matter!? Also, what exactly is causing this?